# Substitute for MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, database

Is there way to create database in one file?

I have a PHP script, is there possible to use PHP
syntax (as Apache) to read correct data from one
single database file?

Something like: http://www.sqlite.org/about.html But this requires more than 1 file.

Comment: Not using mySQL. What is your end goal with this?

Comment: Just use simple CSV file

Comment: Being able to store organized and accessible data in one file.

Comment: sqlite gives you a single file with indexing

Comment: Serialize / JSON Encode to flatfile

Comment: "use PHP syntax (as Apache)..." - this makes no sense. Why is SQLite unsuitable for you?

Comment: Sqlite doesn't need more than one file? SQLite got for each database one file, not more!

Comment: I think asker does not want to use multiple/long PHP source files...

Comment: If a CSV will do, then SQLite will as well and will do so much more.

Comment: @Koshinae Maybe not long, but it won't be tiny. MySQL can be hacked, but hash, salted and encrypted data not.

Comment: @Dave Nowadays, everything is hackable. Ask Facebook, Microsoft, Apple and NSA

Comment: I have no idea what any of that has to do with single file databases, PHP, Apache or CSVs.

Comment: I have no idea, why Dave says I am wrong. When so far I know, it's not wrong.

Comment: So I can hack your server and download your text file or your lack of knowledge would let you putting your text file in a web accessible location so i can just download it. At least to gain access to mysql they have to inject (your code failure) or hack the actual server and then if you salt/hash/store your data in mysql they have the encryption to get past ontop of that.  a flat text file is much easier to handle both for downloading and bruteforcing the contents and you loose any useful tools for relationships and searching/indexing etc.  Using a CSV for data storage is just plain wrong.

Comment: So far I remember, it will take like min. 1000 years to Bruteforce hash of salted encryption. Since encryption has strange "white-space" looking characters, which will result unstandard salt and then normal looking but unstandard hash. It won't be that easy to do it. Or am I wrong? If that would be that easy, I wouldn't get 4 downvotes on InformationSecurity when I pasted encryption.

Comment: Look, I am not disrespecting you. You are surely better than me. But there are things even beginners or "n00b"'s like me know. Hash is bruteforcible that's true. But it won't only be hash.

Comment: Not saying you're wrong at all, but "encryption" and "hash" by itself doesn't mean anything. It depends on *how* you hash and *how* you encrypt and *how* you store your key used in the encryption. Hashing *and* encrypting passwords really really well is pretty secure, yes. But just hashing them well is just as good in practice, you don't need encryption on top of it. So, that's a questionable approach to begin with. I won't put any weight into the fact that you're "hashing and encrypting" until I see *how* you do it. And I still don't know what any of that has to do with MySQL.

Comment: Ask Dave. He started topic about it. With "Wrong but carry on".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use just simple [Comma Separated Vlaues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) (CSV) file.

PHP has several standart function to work with CSV-files data:

- [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php);
- [fputcsv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php).

Comment: Upvoted, I will select this as good answer, as soon as SO will allow me to. Thank you so much for reliable answer.